# Inverse table search

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a table search but I would like to make an inverse search. In my jQuery code how can I exchange .hide() -> .show() and .show() -> .hide() when a `<input type="checkbox" checked>` is false. And when checkbox is checked undo everything.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search..." id="search_field">
<input type="checkbox" checked>
<table id="myTable" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr class="myHead">
            <th>XDFFD</th>
            <th>DFDDY</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

    $('#search_field').on('keyup', function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        var patt = new RegExp(value, "i");
        $('#myTable').find('tr').each(function() {
            if (!($(this).find('td').text().search(patt) >= 0)) {
                $(this).not('.myHead').hide();
            }
            if (($(this).find('td').text().search(patt) >= 0)) {
                $(this).show();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: please prvide some code

Comment: What is an inverse table search?  Can you play here and comeback when you have some code?  https://jsfiddle.net/SkiWether/RAEtg/

Comment: @quantumPuter when I search for 1, 1 and 2 will appear, but I want 3 and 4 and 5 and 6 to appear, this is inverse search. When <input type="checkbox" checked> normal search, when checkbox is false inverse search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You check if the checkbox is `checked` or not using `is(":checked")` this will give  true or false so depending on this show or hide trs.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('#search_field').on('keyup', function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  var patt = new RegExp(value, "i");
  var checks = $(".checkbox").is(":checked"); //check if checkbox is checked
  console.log(checks)
  if (value != "") {
    $('#myTable tbody').find('tr').each(function() {
      var condition = $(this).find('td').text().search(patt) >= 0
      //checked
      if (checks) {
        //show and hide..
        condition ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide()
      } else {
        condition ? $(this).hide() : $(this).show()
      }
    });
  } else {
    $('#myTable tbody > tr').show()
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Search..." id="search_field">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" checked>
<table id="myTable" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr class="myHead">
      <th>XDFFD</th>
      <th>DFDDY</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative version of the same using a little jQuery extension to make `:contains()` case insensitive:

```js
// jQuery extension from https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-jquery-contains-case-insensitive/
$.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
 return function( elem ) {return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0; };
});

$('input').on('input', function() {
  $('#myTable tbody tr').each((i,tr)=>$(tr).toggle
    ( $('td:contains('+$('#search_field').val()+')',tr).length>0 === $(".checkbox").is(":checked") )
  )
}).first().focus();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Search..." id="search_field">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" checked>
<table id="myTable" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr class="myHead">
      <th>XDFFD</th>
      <th>DFDDY</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1 one</td>
      <td>2 two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3 Three</td>
      <td>4 Four</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5 FIVE</td>
      <td>6 SIX</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The `===`comparison of two booleans is in fact something like an XOR condition between the two expressions. The result will be `true` if *both*  or *none* of the expressions

```
$('td:contains('+$('#search_field').val()+')',tr).length>0
```

and

```
$(".checkbox").is(":checked")
```

are `true`. And this will be used directly in the `.toggle()` method to show or hide the current `<tr>`.